# How to get DocumentStore active session count in Raven?

Tags: c#, ravendb

We have some performance issues in our app, so we want to test how many active session we have at a time. So the question is how can I get active session count from `DocumentStore` object?

Comment: You might have to use Windows Performance Monitor. http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/administration/perf-counters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that unless you track it yourself.
Nothing in RavenDB tracks active sessions.